# Outlook Printing - All Events

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, sharepoint-2013

I recently was able to get management to stop using poorly built monthly calendar DOC files and to start using SharePoint calendars to keep try of events and so forth. Gives them searchable records and allows me to do actual programming based on events and injecting events into SharePoint programmatically when needed.

The problem is that they dont have a good way to print events because the print function from the browser is garbage. But when you link the calendar to Outlook it is well formatted but if a day has more than 4 events it just adds "X more events" below. Thus making the events hidden from a printed copy.

Do you have a suggestion for management being able to print monthly view calendars and show all events on a busy calendar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The **Calendar Printing Assistant** might help you here. Its an official addon for Outlook that specializes in printing your calendar in Outlook.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=16645